Can you calculate the radius of a hypothetical singular surface inside a black hole from observing changes to its linear momentum?
Say there is a ball of unknown radius surrounded by a bubble. The ball represents a hypothetical singular surface inside a black hole and the bubble represents the event horizon.
If you threw marbles into the bubble at different angles (let's pretend the bubble does not pop), some of the marbles will hit the ball and others will go into the bubble but miss the ball. You could determine the radius of the ball based on what marbles at what angles cause the ball's linear momentum to change.
Could you do the same thing with a black hole but from observations on how its linear momentum changes from stars entering the event horizon at different angles?

Related recent post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/821460/2451

What are you specifically looking for, the black hole case or the non black hole case?

What do you mean black hole or non black hole case?

No, because as an observer outside the event horizon, you will never be able to see an object cross the event horizon. (See This post)

Sure you won't see an object cross the event horizon but that doesn't mean it doesn't cross the event horizon. Couldn't you still look at how the black hole's linear momentum changes even if you can't see the object cross? Unless you are saying nothing can cross the event horizon?

From the perspective of an outside observer, the object actually never crosses.

Yes it fades away. Just because you dont see it cross doesn't mean it doesn't cross.

@user414142 How do you get info about events that are in your future? Please see  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696441/123208 especially my H-bomb analogy.

@user414142 It doesn't just fade away. It approaches the horizon asymptotically because of time dilation.
